# Resize two axes at once h5py

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

Is there a way to `resize` two axes by appending new data?. I was able to append new data to one axis using `resize` and `maxshape` following Docs in [h5py Docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#Dataset.maxshape). 
But what I am trying now is append data to two axes at once by using the same logic as appending to one axis. But what I am getting is a `TypeError: Can't broadcast (10000, 500, 2) -> (10000, 1000, 2)`. This might be due to the chunks sizes but can't figure it out.
Any suggestion
This is what I tried so far:

```
def create_hdf5_file(name, path, shape, chunks = None):
    """create a hdf5 file given a path, shape and chunks.
    If chunks is not given file will be created without
    any chunk. Default chunks  is equal to False. The file 
    will be compressed as gzip with a level of compression equals
    to 4. This function will append data to the hdf5 file"""

    with h5py.File(str(path+'/'+name+'.hdf5'), 'w') as f:
        dset = f.create_dataset(str(name), compression = 'gzip', shape= (shape), chunks= (chunks), \
            maxshape = (None, None, shape[2]))
        n = 10**5 # size for axis 0
        #m = 5*10**3 size for axis 1
        while dset.shape[0] < n: # and dset.shape[1] < m:
            dset.resize(dset.shape[0]+10**4, axis=0)
            #dset.resize(dset.shape[1]+5*10**2, axis = 1)
            dset[-10**4:] = np.random.randint(2, size=(10**4, shape[1], shape[2]))
            #dset[-5*10**2:] = np.random.randint(2, size =(shape[0], 5*10**2, shape[2]))
            print(dset.shape)
        print('Final dataset size: {}'.format(dset.shape))
        print('Chunks size: {}'.format(dset.chunks))
    print('HDF5 file created as: {}'.format(str(name)+'.hdf5'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_hdf5_file(name='test',path='/home/neither/Desktop', \
    shape = (10000, 500,2), chunks= (1000,5000,2))
```

I commented what I was trying while appending data into a new axis. But I get the previous error. Appending data into axis 0 works as expected but when trying to do the same with both axes fails.

Comment: If axis 1 is resized to 1000, you need to use a slice to write a size 500 array to it.  dset[-10000:, :500] = np.ones((10000,500)).

Answer (score 0):

Writing to a resizable `dataset` is just like writing to a numpy array - you have to specify the correct size of a slice - in all dimensions.

When expanding in 2 dimensions, it requires some care to fill in all the blocks correctly.  Not only are you adding rows, but also columns:

```
dset = f.create_dataset(str(name),...
    maxshape = (None, None, shape[2]))
dset[...] = np.ones(shape)     # initial fill
print(dset.shape)
for i in range(2,4):
    dset.resize(dset.shape[0]+shape[0], axis=0)
    dset[-shape[0]:, :, :] = np.ones((shape[0], dset.shape[1], shape[2]))*i
    # add an axis 0 block and fill that
    print(dset.shape)
    for j in range(2):
        dset.resize(dset.shape[1]+shape[1], axis = 1)
        dset[-shape[0]:, -shape[1]:, : ] = np.ones(shape)*(i+j)
        # add an axis 1 block and fill that
        print(dset.shape)
```

resulting print:

```
(1000, 500, 2)
(2000, 500, 2)
(2000, 1000, 2)
(2000, 1500, 2)
(3000, 1500, 2)
(3000, 2000, 2)
(3000, 2500, 2)
Final dataset size: (3000, 2500, 2)
```

But I didn't fill in all expanded space.

With `shape = (3,2,1)`

```
(3, 2, 1)
(6, 2, 1)
(6, 4, 1)
(6, 6, 1)
(9, 6, 1)
(9, 8, 1)
(9, 10, 1)
Final dataset size: (9, 10, 1)
Chunks size: (3, 2, 1)
```

And the actual data  `print(np.squeeze(dset[...]))`:

```
[[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 2 3 3 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 2 3 3 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 2 3 3 0 0 0 0]
 [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4]
 [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4]
 [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4]]
```

with 0's filling chunks that I resized but didn't explicitly fill.

Comment: so, what I was trying makes no sense?. I didn't realize about the difference between expanding and filling. You would suggest change what I did?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do with `resize`.  As I demonstrate, it just makes the array (on the file) larger.  The initial fill is with the `fillvalue` (default 0).  The rest is your responsibility, and ordinary `numpy` array assignment rules apply.

Comment: I see, thanks. I am trying to expand the array with random 0,1 values just to get an initial idea of resize function. I though that using resize was a good alternative to create a file and expand it later in order not to load all into memory.